# Vue Router switch rendered Component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

In my Vue application I want to include an unauthorized page. Therefore I started to manipulate my router. It looks like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        addGuard(<RouteConfigurationView>{
            path: "/somePath/:id",
            name: "someName",
            component: () => import("../pages/MyComponent.vue"),
            hidden: true
        })
     ]
});

function addGuard(route: RouteConfigSingleView): RouteConfigSingleView {
    route.beforeEnter = (to, from, next) => {
        if(to.params.id == 5) { // Just for example.
            route.component = () => import("../pages/Unauthorized.vue");
        }
        next();
    };
    return route;
}
```

When I enter the given route, the original component (MyComponent) is being loaded and my switching is being ignored.
Is there any way my use case can be implemented with the Vue tools?

Comment: What you're doing won't work because you shouldn't be changing the route definition after the router is created. The component associated with each route is fixed and shouldn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing route's component you should create `UnauthorizedRoute`   with `Unauthorized.vue` component assigned to it.

Then instead of reassigning the component in current route, you should redirect user to that route:

`next({name: 'UnauthorizedRoute'})`

Comment: But isnt it bad practice to have a route like "https://myapp.com/somepath/unauthorized"?

Comment: Well such route could be misleading. I would reccomend give it a path such as `403` or `401` or just redirect to a login page if that's what you need. Generally user should know what is happening. Depending to the pattern you want to fallow you could redirect to 404 page. There is no bad answer here.